# Reverse hash lookup query

Tags: mysql, sha

i have an web service and one of the parameter our clients needs to use is a custom key. this key is a hash of sha1

```
eg:
bce700635afccfd8690836f37e4b4e9cf46d9c08
```

then when the client call our web service i have to check few things:

- is client active
- is client can submit via webservice and service

now my problem is this:

i have a query:

```
$sql = "SELECT permission, is_active FROM clients WHERE sha1(concat(id,key)) = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($key) . "'";
```

Am i doing the right thing? or there's a better way?
thanks

Comment: Are you basically using the key as a session ID? If so, you might consider instead using PHP sessions. Very easy and secure. http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: @JonathanM no, the key is a sha1 of the client id + random key (we locally store in the table) and we give to the client. so when we call our site he needs to use it eg: http://ws.domain.com/bce700635afccfd8690836f37e4b4e9cf46d9c08/ AND he POST username and password and other variables;

Comment: @ErinTucker: If there's a random key included in the hash, then how come your query just has `sha1(id)`?

Comment: @ruakh oops i forgot it thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This approach is expensive, since, every time you run this query, MySQL will have to examine every single record in `clients` and compute the SHA-1 hash of its `id` and `key`. (I'm assuming here that `clients` has more than a few rows, or at least, that you'd like to use an approach that supports the case where `clients` has more than a few rows.)

Why don't you add a new field called (say) `id_key_sha1`? You can use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html) to keep the field populated, and add an [index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) on it. This approach should perform *much* better.

**Edited to add:** You mention that the client, in addition to passing in this SHA-1 hash, also has to submit a username and password? I don't know what your table structure looks like, but I'm guessing that it would make more sense to find the client record based on the username first, and then comparing the SHA-1 hash for that specific record, rather than trying to find the record by the SHA-1 hash.

Answer (score 0):

You should not applying function into your LHS column where doing filtering in mysql,
this make not possible for mysql to make use of index for comparison.

An example will allow make use on index :-

```
where key = SHA1(CONCAT(id, :key))

// where the :key = user submitted api key
// and in this case mysql able to fetch the matched rows via index
```